# reduce work in mysql by creating a static page?

Tags: php, mysql, load, reduce

lets say i have 3 tables in my database, with the same primary id number and 15 properties (5 for each table). I do a query in table_1 where property_1="something",i take the id's and i print all their properties with echo and html.(Is there a better way?) let's say i reach some time that i'll take for example 10000 id's with 15 properties each(and i'll use a correct pagination). Will this increase a lot the load page time? (i'll use shared hosting) If yes is it possible to create static page that refresh their content in time intervals?

(this is my first php-mysql site any help is appreciated)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query multiple tables, you should use a [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you use pagination you won't have any problem because MySql has `Limit` keyword that let you skip some rows and take a specific number of rows. This will reduce the set of value returned by the query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have proper indexes, 10000 is pretty small table. 
Of course, it depends of number of visitors, if you have thousands of hits per minute, adding cache will help.